# How to get list of all docker-machine images for google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, command-line-interface, docker-machine

I'm creating docker-machines in Google Cloud with the shell command

```
docker-machine create --driver google \
     --google-project my-project \
     --google-zone my-zone \
     --google-machine-image debian-cloud/global/images/debian-10-buster-v20191210 \
     machine-name
```

As you see, i use the image debian-10-buster-v20191210. But I want to switch the version of the image to a less recent one. And the problem is that I can't find the place where the list of 
such images (debian-10-buster-v*) can be found. Can you please help me to find the place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining a list of available images can be done using the [gcloud command line](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstarts).

`--show deprecated` indicates you want to see ALL images, not just the latest
`--filter=` only selects images with a starting name of debian-10-buster

```
    $ gcloud compute images list --filter="name=debian-10-buster" --show-deprecated
    NAME                        PROJECT       FAMILY     DEPRECATED  STATUS
    debian-10-buster-v20191115  debian-cloud  debian-10  DEPRECATED  READY
    debian-10-buster-v20191121  debian-cloud  debian-10  DEPRECATED  READY
    debian-10-buster-v20191210  debian-cloud  debian-10              READY
```

You can find additional information in the [gcloud Images List documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/list).